# How to redirect using AJAX and Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am new to Ajax and I have already seen this question but I am having this issue in chrome console

http://s2.postimg.org/6vdhlvyh5/Capture.jpg

Here's the php code...

```
 $rs1 = [
        'error' => $blank_err,
        'url' => "http://localhost/experimental/view.php"
    ];
    echo json_encode($rs1);
    exit;
```

Here's Ajax code...

```
$.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"validate_signin.php",
            datatype:"JSON",

            data:{

                femail:femail,fpass:fpass,submit_signin: true
            },
    success:function(resp){
                    if (resp.error !== "") {
                            $("#err").html(resp.error);
                        } else {
                            window.location.href=resp.url;
                        }
```

and due to wrong backslashes it's not redirecting
I even tried using

```
$url=$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]."/experimental/view.php";
```

in php page and sending back to ajax with json_encode($rs1);

Comment: What is `$blank_err`?

Comment: it is storing my errors generated in the db manipulation page and returning them to my js page

Comment: Yes, but what is it? Is it a string? Is it a boolean false? Have you checked?

Comment: it's string. I am storing my defined errors in that variable. I am not having any problems with $blank_err variable. it's just when the browser is parsing the url it is showing directory backslash '\' along with '/' instead of '/' and dats why its not able to redirect

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSON.parse` for parsing the `response` and then redirecting as

```
success:function(resp){
                var data = JSON.parse(resp);
                if (data.error !== "") {
                        $("#err").html(data.error);
                    } else {
                        window.location.href=data.url;
                    }
```

Comment: The code says `datatype:"JSON",`. Calling `JSON.parse` on it will try to double decode it, which will fail.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend, you can use `jQuery.ajax()` for this. this is easy to use and control ajax functionality.  Follow this link http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: i am using it i haven't posted the whole code if it helps i will put the whole code.

Comment: The code in the question **is** using jQuery.ajax. (That was easy enough to tell even before the question was edited to make it explicit).